# How To Make Custom Shape In React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, user-interface

Can anybody help to make such kind of shape in React Native ? I highlighted with red in picture shape.

I tried in this way

```
const Header = memo(() => {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        width: '100%',
        height: 120,
        borderRadius: 30,
        backgroundColor: 'orange',
        transform: [{ scaleX: 1 }]
      }}
    />
  )
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this.
Here is solution

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native'
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient'
const { width: W } = Dimensions.get('window')

   <LinearGradient
    start={{ x: 0.8, y: 0.2 }}
    end={{ x: 0.5, y: 1.0 }}
    locations={[0.1, 0.9]}
    colors={[colors.HEADER_GRADIENT_1, colors.HEADER_GRADIENT_2]}
    style={{
      height: 245,
      width: W - 120,
      left: 50,
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      top: -85,
      borderRadius: 150,
      transform: [{ scaleX: 3 }]
    }}
  >
    <StatusBar translucent={true} backgroundColor={'transparent'} />
  </LinearGradient>
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not react native.
However I do think you will get a far end with the CSS in here:

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
  top: -75px;
  left: -10%;
  height: 250px;
  width: 120%;
  background-color: #555;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, red, yellow)
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
<div>
```

Comment: No problem, if you want to use other shapes at the bottom we usually use an image with alpha layer

Comment: Got you, I am making my personal project. So I am trying around. Checkout, I found solution to my problem